# Creating a responsive two column, centered <ul> with left-aligned <li>'s with FA icons as "bullets" within a multi-column container in bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am having difficulty creating a centered unordered list that has left aligned list items within a multi-column container. This list should also have FA icons as the "bullets", and should start vertically aligned to the icons from the "honors and awards" section above it, and should expand out to right to use up the available space. I would also like it to be responsive so that when the screen size becomes smaller, the spacing between the multi-column  decreases. I don't know if a table would be better for this then?

My Current Code:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:400,700,800|Open+Sans:400,700,800');
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  //width: 100%;
  min-width: 300px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif !important;
}

.navbar {
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif !important;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
{
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif !important;
  font-weight: 400
}

h5,
h6 {
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif !important;
  font-weight: 800;
}

.inlineFontChange {
  display: inline;
}


/*.progress{
      flex-direction: row;
    }
    */

.ulCenter {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

p {
  text-align: justify;
  color: #3B424C;
}

#profilePic {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 28px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  float: right;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  #profilePic {
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    justify-content: center;
    display: block;
  }
}

// .navbar{
// background-color: #3B424C; //This is the color of the actual background; navbar-dark-color is the link color!
//background:none !important;
// width: 100%;
// }
.jarallax {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

.jarallax>.jarallax-img {
  position: absolute;
  object-fit: cover;
  /* support for plugin https://github.com/bfred-it/object-fit-images */
  font-family: 'object-fit: cover;';
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}


/* Help from: https://free.nkdev.info/jarallax/*/

.overlay {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 75vh;
  background-color: rgba(190, 190, 190, 0.6);
}

@media only screen and (max-height: 740px) {
  .overlay {
    height: 100vh;
  }
}

.overlay-cell {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  //top: 35%;
  top: 34%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.heroSection {
  height: 100vh; //Controls the height of the Hero
}

.subSection {
  height: 300px; //Controls the height of the subsection jarallax
  margin: 0;
}

#baseNav {
  //font-family: 'Yantramanav', sans-serif;
  //font-weight: 700;
  //font-size: 20px;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  //overflow: hidden;
  //background-color: #3b424c;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
}

#baseNav.hide {
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}

.navbar {
  top: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: fixed; //THIS IS KEY! IN ORDER TO GET NAV OVER PICTURE
  width: 100%
}

.navbar-nav .nav-link {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  @media (max-width: 34em) {
    font-weight:normal;
  }
  .navbar-nav .nav-item {
    padding: 0 1rem;
    @media(max-width: 34 em) {
      padding: 0;
    }
  }
}

.navbar-toggler {
  cursor: pointer;
}

// This adjusts the Main Menu and Dropdown (submenu) colors
$bgMain: rgba(59,
66,
76,
0); // This color '0' at the end is for transparency for navbar hiding
$bgDropdown: rgba(59,
66,
76,
1);
$bgHighlight: hsl(184,
85%,
43%);
$colDefault: #ffffff;
$colHighlight: #95ce33;
$dropDown: true;
.navbar {
  background-color: $bgMain;
  .navbar-brand {
    color: $colDefault;
    &:hover,
    &:focus {
      color: $colHighlight;
    }
  }
  .navbar-text {
    color: $colDefault;
  }
  .navbar-nav {
    .nav-link {
      color: $colDefault;
      border-radius: .25rem;
      margin: 0 0.25em;
      &:not(.disabled) {
        &:hover,
        &:focus {
          color: $colHighlight;
        }
      }
    }
    @if ($dropDown) {
      .dropdown-menu {
        background-color: $bgDropdown;
        border-color: $bgHighlight;
        .dropdown-item {
          color: $colDefault;
          &:hover,
          &:focus,
          &.active {
            color: $colHighlight;
            background-color: $bgHighlight;
          }
        }
        .dropdown-divider {
          border-top-color: $bgHighlight;
        }
      }
    }
    .nav-item.active,
    .nav-item.show {
      .nav-link,
      .nav-link:hover,
      .nav-link:focus {
        color: $colHighlight;
        background-color: $bgHighlight;
      }
    }
  }
  .navbar-toggle {
    border-color: $bgHighlight;
    &:hover,
    &:focus {
      background-color: $bgHighlight;
    }
    .navbar-toggler-icon {
      color: $colDefault;
    }
  }
  .navbar-collapse,
  .navbar-form {
    border-color: $colDefault;
  }
  .navbar-link {
    color: $colDefault;
    &:hover {
      color: $colHighlight;
    }
  }
}

@media (max-width: 575px) {
  .navbar-expand-sm .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu {
    .dropdown-item {
      color: $colDefault;
      &:hover,
      &:focus {
        color: $colHighlight;
      }
    }
    .dropdown-item.active {
      color: $colHighlight;
      background-color: $bgHighlight;
    }
  }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-expand-md .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu {
    .dropdown-item {
      color: $colDefault;
      &:hover,
      &:focus {
        color: $colHighlight;
      }
    }
    .dropdown-item.active {
      color: $colHighlight;
      background-color: $bgHighlight;
    }
  }
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .navbar-expand-lg .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu {
    .dropdown-item {
      color: $colDefault;
      &:hover,
      &:focus {
        color: $colHighlight;
      }
    }
    .dropdown-item.active {
      color: $colHighlight;
      background-color: $bgHighlight;
    }
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1199px) {
  .navbar-expand-xl .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu {
    .dropdown-item {
      color: $colDefault;
      &:hover,
      &:focus {
        color: $colHighlight;
      }
    }
    .dropdown-item.active {
      color: $colHighlight;
      background-color: $bgHighlight;
    }
  }
}

.navbar-expand .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu {
  .dropdown-item {
    color: $colDefault;
    &:hover,
    &:focus {
      color: $colHighlight;
    }
  }
  .dropdown-item.active {
    color: $colHighlight;
    background-color: $bgHighlight;
  }
}

#about {
  padding-top: 3em;
  padding-bottom: 3em;
}

#mainOverlay {
  margin: 0;
}

.logoImages {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
}

//This is for the FA Icon alignment in the Skills list
.iconShift {
  //Moves the Honors and Awards heading to the left bc of the way the margin works on the FA Icons... Center doesn't take into accpint the icon
  margin-left: 40px;
}

dl {
  margin-left: 40px
}

dt {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  position: relative;
}

dt:not(:first-of-type) {
  margin-top: 2em
}

dt:before {
  content: "";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  left: -40px;
  // position:absolute;
  top: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 8px;
}

dt.achievement:before {
  content: "\f091";
  //These two nested lines control the FA Icon animation! because of the fact i am using a ::before element, I cannot use the native fa spinning classes explicitly in the html
  -webkit-animation: fa-spin 2s infinite linear;
  animation: fa-spin 2s infinite linear;
}

dt.academic:before {
  content: "\f19d";
}

dd {
  margin-left: 0
}

dd.description {
  font-size: 1 em;
}

/////

/*



      li:before {
        content: ""; 
        font-family: FontAwesome;
        left: -40px;
        position:absolute;
        top: 5px;
    }

    li.achievement:before {
        content: "\f091"; 

      //These two nested lines control the FA Icon animation! because of the fact i am using a ::before element, I cannot use the native fa spinning classes explicitly in the html
      -webkit-animation: fa-spin 2s infinite linear;
      animation: fa-spin 2s infinite linear;
    }

    li.puzzle:before {
      content: "\f12e"; 
      -webkit-animation: fa-spin 2s infinite linear;
      animation: fa-spin 2s infinite linear;
    }

    li.wrench:before {
      content: "\f0ad"; 
      -webkit-animation: fa-spin 2s infinite linear;
      animation: fa-spin 2s infinite linear;
    }

    li.academic:before {
      content: "\f19d"; 
      -webkit-animation: fa-spin 2s infinite linear;
      animation: fa-spin 2s infinite linear;
    }

    li.plane:before {
      content: "\f072"; 
      -webkit-animation: fa-spin 2s infinite linear;
      animation: fa-spin 2s infinite linear;
    }

    li.car:before {
      content: "\f1b9"; 
      -webkit-animation: fa-spin 2s infinite linear;
      animation: fa-spin 2s infinite linear;
    }

    li.volunteer:before {
      content: "\f0c0"; 
      -webkit-animation: fa-spin 2s infinite linear;
      animation: fa-spin 2s infinite linear;
    }

    li.camera:before {
      content: "\f030"; 
      -webkit-animation: fa-spin 2s infinite linear;
      animation: fa-spin 2s infinite linear;
    }

    */

.honors {
  justify-content: center;
}

li.puzzle::before {
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  font-size: 1.1em;
  content: "\f12e";
  margin-right: 8px;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-animation: fa-spin 2s infinite linear;
  animation: fa-spin 2s infinite linear;
}

li.wrench::before {
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  font-size: 1.1em;
  content: "\f0ad";
  margin-right: 8px;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-animation: fa-spin 2s infinite linear;
  animation: fa-spin 2s infinite linear;
}

li.plane::before {
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  font-size: 1.1em;
  content: "\f072";
  margin-right: 8px;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-animation: fa-spin 2s infinite linear;
  animation: fa-spin 2s infinite linear;
}

li.car::before {
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  font-size: 1.1em;
  content: "\f1b9";
  margin-right: 8px;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-animation: fa-spin 2s infinite linear;
  animation: fa-spin 2s infinite linear;
}

li.volunteer::before {
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  font-size: 1.1em;
  content: "\f0c0";
  margin-right: 8px;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-animation: fa-spin 2s infinite linear;
  animation: fa-spin 2s infinite linear;
}

li.camera::before {
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  font-size: 1em;
  content: "\f030";
  margin-right: 8px;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-animation: fa-spin 2s infinite linear;
  animation: fa-spin 2s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes fa-spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);
    transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}

.shift {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.barbie {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.baribieitem {
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section id="about">
  <h5 class="text-center pb-3">Ready to tackle any challenge. Proven by performance.</h5>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 ">
        <!--- Instruments -->
        <h4 class="text-center pt-3">Instruments</h4>
        <div class="progress mb-3" style="height: 35px">
          <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 75%">CombiFlash® Rf+ </div>
        </div>
        <div class="progress mb-3" style="height: 35px">
          <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 75%">Mass Spectrometer (GC-MS, ESI-MS, APCI-MS)</div>
        </div>
        <div class="progress mb-3" style="height: 35px">
          <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 75%">NMR</div>
        </div>
        <div class="progress mb-3" style="height: 35px">
          <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 75%">UV-Vis Spectrophotometer </div>
        </div>
        <!--- Languages -->
        <h4 class="text-center pt-5">Languages</h4>
        <div class="progress mb-3" style="height: 35px">
          <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 75%">English </div>
        </div>
        <div class="progress mb-3" style="height: 35px">
          <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 75%">Español</div>
        </div>
        <div class="progress mb-3" style="height: 35px">
          <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 75%">Français</div>
        </div>
        <!--- Software -->
        <h4 class="text-center pt-5">Software</h4>
        <div class="progress mb-3" style="height: 35px">
          <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 75%">ChemDraw </div>
        </div>
        <div class="progress mb-3" style="height: 35px">
          <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 75%">Spartan ’16</div>
        </div>
        <div class="progress mb-3" style="height: 35px">
          <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 75%">Bruker® TopSpin</div>
        </div>
        <div class="progress mb-3" style="height: 35px">
          <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 75%">Adobe® Suite (Illustrator, Photoshop, and etc..)</div>
        </div>
        <div class="progress mb-3" style="height: 35px">
          <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 75%">Wolfram® Mathematica</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6 honors offset-md-2">
        <h4 class="text-center iconShift pt-3"> Notable Honors and Awards</h4>
        <dl>
          <dt class="achievement">Boy Scouts of America Eagle Scout Rank</dt>
          <dd class="description">The Highest Rank in Scouting</dd>
          <dd>April 2014</dd>

          <dt class="academic">Principal's Award of Excellence </dt>
          <dd class="description">Recognized for Scientific Research</dd>
          <dd>June 2013 & 2014</dd>


          <dt class="academic fa-spinner">Presidents Award for Educational Excellence</dt>
          <dd class="description">U.S. Department of Education | President Barack H. Obama</dd>
        </dl>


        <div class="container float-center">
          <h4 class="text-center pt-5">Hobbies and Interests</h4>
          <div class="row float-right">
            <div class="col" style="column-count: 2; column-gap: 15em;">
              <ul class="barbie list-unstyled">
                <li class="barbieitem pb-2 pt-2 puzzle text-left">Puzzles</li>
                <li class="barbieitem pb-2 pr-4 plane ">Travel</li>
                <li class="barbieitem pb-2 wrench text-left">Handy Work</li>
                <li class="barbieitem pb-2 plane text-left">Travel</li>
                <li class="barbieitem pb-2 volunteer text-left">Volunteering</li>
                <li class="barbieitem pb-2 car text-left">Automobiles</li>
                <li class="barbieitem pb-2 plane text-left">Travel</li>
                <li class="barbieitem pb-2 camera text-left">Photography</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: This question needs to be simplified to a minimal example